# Reference in LaTeX chapter style

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I would like to add a note in the LaTeX Chapter environment that the work I am describing in the following has been published in a paper. In other words, it should look something like this:

```
Chapter 6

The Evolution in research

The research described in this Chapter has been published in:
R. Moor and J.Morris. The Evolution of Research, Workshop on
Education, 2010, pp. 180-190


Once upon a time ....
```

Or alternatively:

```
The research described in this Chapter has been published in:
R. Moor and J.Morris. The Evolution of Research, Workshop on
Education, 2010, pp. 180-190

Chapter 6

The Evolution in research


Once upon a time ....
```

Anyone an idea if there is something like a template for doing that in LaTeX?

Comment: Is this meant to be your contribution to an edited collection?  Formatting the chapter is then not your problem.  Putting the information in a `\thanks` note in the title seems appropriate.

Answer (score 11):

With the KOMA classes you could define a chapter preamble with the command `\setchapterpreamble`. Using a BibTeX style that has full citation support, e.g. [biblatex](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), you could do the following:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Moor.Morris2010,
  author = {R. Moor and J. Morris},
  title = {The Evolution of Research},
    subtitle = {Workshop on Education},
  year = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=authortitle
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\setchapterpreamble{%
  \begin{quote}
      The research described in this Chapter has been published in: 
      \fullcite[180-190]{Moor.Morris2010}.
    \end{quote}
}
\chapter{The Evolution in research}

Once upon a time~\ldots
\end{document}
```

You could put anything inside the `\setchapterpreamble` command, not only a quote environment, but also plain text. You could e.g. also use KOMA’s `\dictum` command:

```
\setchapterpreamble{%
  \dictum{%
    The research described in this Chapter has been published in: 
    \fullcite[180-190]{Moor.Morris2010}.
}}
\renewcommand*{\dictumwidth}{.5\textwidth}
```

Comment: Very nice and complete answer!

Comment: It is a very nice approach, thanks for your help ;)