# Publication details below chapter title

Tags: sectioning, chapters, epigraphs

I would like to add some publication details below the title of the chapter. I got here already some useful comments, but I decided now to go with the epigraph environment. At the moment, the code looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\renewcommand{\epigraphwidth}{3.5in}
\renewcommand{\epigraphrule}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\epigraph{The research described in this Chapter has been published in:}{
 P. Moss, J. Morrison, and G. Ranger. {\it Seed production and seedling survival 
 in a $50$ year-old stand of Corsican pine in Britain}. Advances in Seed Physiology
 and Technology 2007.
 }

 \noindent Here the chapter text goes..

 \end{document}
```

It looks okayish, however, I am still a bit unsure about the appearance; it just does not look right... Maybe I can try left aligning the text, that might help. Anyone
else an suggestion how I could improve this so that it looks a bit more "professional".

Many thanks for your input!

Comment: I'm not sure this question has a well-defined answer. I'd say that an epigraph seems like the wrong place to put this information. I sometimes see that information given in footnotes.

Comment: You already had a very good answer on your [previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/reference-in-latex-chapter-style), what was wrong with that? Could you post comments or concerns by editing your old question instead of opening a new one?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushleft}
\renewcommand{\epigraphwidth}{3.5in}
\renewcommand{\epigraphrule}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\epigraph{The research described in this Chapter has been published in:}{
 P. Moss, J. Morrison, and G. Ranger. {\it Seed production and seedling survival 
 in a $50$ year-old stand of Corsican pine in Britain}. Advances in Seed Physiology
 and Technology 2007.
 }

 \noindent Here the chapter text goes..

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I've put your code in a code block to make it easier to see.